# Overriding a constructor via super() providing fewer parameters that the parent constructor requires

Tags: python, oop, initialization

I'm reading this [tutorial about inheritance](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-inheritance-in-python-3) in Python. It proposes the following example (I simplified it a bit):

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name="Fish"):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name            

class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__(self)
```

Surprisingly (to me), you can create instances of `Trout` without giving it any name and it does not raise an exception. I don't understand why the call `super().__init__(self)` does not fail. The constructor of the parent class **requires** the `first_name` parameter! How come you are not allowed to create an instance of Fish without giving it a name (i.e. `Fish()` fails), but you can call the same constructor from a child class without problems (i.e. `Trout()` works)!?

Other way of posing this doubt is saying that I'd expect that the only correct way to implement the child class is with:

```
class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, first_name, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__(self, first_name)
```

Comment: Because you're passing `self` *as `first_name`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed `self` as the first argument to `super().__init__`.  Look at the first_name of a Trout instance, you'll get `<__main__.Trout object at 0x7f93635e8130>` (with a different memory address) - `self` is implied in method calls, so passing `self` explicitly makes it the first argument.

Edit to add (as this wasn't super clear, I realize):
the correct form of your example would look like

```
class Fish:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name="Fish"):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name            

class Trout(Fish):
    def __init__(self, first_name, water = "freshwater"):
        self.water = water
        super().__init__(first_name) # note that self is not required here
```

Comment: OK, but then it's misleading. Trout().first_name is not what we expect it to be. Right? In order to have the expected behaviour you'd have to use the code I posted below (I edited the question while you answered), right?

Comment: no, that code is even wronger.  You don't put `self` in as an argument at all, because it's implied by the dot notation method calling signature.  If you find yourself writing `instance.method(self` at all, in python, you are usually mistaken.

Comment: yep, that's exactly it.  When you call `instance.method(argument)` the method actually receives `method(self, argument)`.  The `self` is implied by it being dotted off of an instance.  That's python syntax simplifying things, but it's definitely confusing at first.

Comment: I'm sorry, we are crossing each other all the time xD. Thanks for the clarification!